# Call restsharp API to get the weather

Tags: c#, .net-core, restsharp

I am trying to call a weather API in C#.

So far this standalone piece of code is not working.

I got the code from postman and I would like to wrap it later into bot framework. I am not familiar with the verbose in the error log.

Instead of retrieving the JSON file from the API call, i just got the following :

```
The program '[9572] ConsoleApp2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

How can I get the JSON the API call?

```cs
using RestSharp;

namespace RestSharpExample
{
    public class Weather
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://www.prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/lat=48.856614lng=2.3522219");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
            request.AddHeader("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=1mqqmau9ndad8j01cq8tgn4t59");
            request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            request.AddHeader("Host", "www.prevision-meteo.ch");
            request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
            request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            // Extracting output data from received response
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

        }
    }
}
```

Here the logs I am getting:

```
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\flabarr\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\ConsoleApp2.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\flabarr\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\RestSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\netstandard.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Collections.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Net.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Private.Uri.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Threading.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Net.Requests.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Security.Principal.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Net.Security.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Web.HttpUtility.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Net.ServicePoint.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Collections.Specialized.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Net.Http.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Threading.Timer.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Net.Sockets.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Net.NameResolution.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Memory.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Security.Claims.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Buffers.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.IO.Compression.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[9572] ConsoleApp2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

As mentionned I am new to this, so any insights on the above would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly isn't working for you? Your example seems to work fine on my computer.

Comment: Can you share more details about your environment? This code works perfectly fine on my computer.

Comment: i forgot "Console.WriteLine(response.Content);" to get the response. Thanks both!